# Attribute statement in Spring SAML extension generated metadata

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml

I am hoping to use the Spring SAML extension as the means to provide SAML authentication for an existing applications. These applications typically expect various attributes to be provided by the IdP generated assertion. These attributes ought to be specified in the SP metadata.

Since I do not see a method in *org.springframework.security.saml.saml2.metadata.ServiceProviderMetadata* to access the attribute statement element, I assume, that the attribute statement has to be added manually to the generated SP metadata, rather than configured in securityContext.xml.

Is that a correct assumption?
Thank you.

Comment: hi @user2634153 did you get success adding custom attributes. I am working on SAML and have same requirements.

Comment: Whats the answer for this? I need to be able to add saml roles to samlresponse. Where to add this?